# install in or on place?

Tags: sentence-construction

- Install a water-shut-off lever (in/on) a place that is easy for the operator to use.

Is it in or on? How about when I use location/position instead of place?
Or is there any better way to say it?

Comment: [*install it **at** a place*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22install+it+at+a+place%22) also occurs. But ***at*** tends to imply the larger context of *geographical* locations, rather than, say, positions within a building.

Comment: Do you want to learn how to use "in" and "on", or do you want us to write a sentence for you?

Comment: Thank you. I am translating technical documents, so I want someone to make the sentence better. But at the same time I want to learn prepositions for describing places for installing devices.

Comment: On is used with flat/2-d things or putting something on top of something else or on a wall. Do either of those make sense in context?

Comment: So we can't use "on" because place or location is not 2-d/flat? Can I use on if I use the word surface? "install it on a surface that is..."?

Comment: Yes you can install on a surface or on a wall.

Comment: ok! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

"In" works, but "on" doesn't.
Another expression is "... install it **where** it's easy for the operator to use."

Comment: Thank you very much. So we never use "on" before "a place/position/location that/where..."?  Also, is it okay to say, " install it so that it is easy for the operator to use"? Do I need to put "in a proper place" or something like that before "so that"?

Comment: Not quite right; some places could take "on". For example, "install it **on** this table, not that one." Some other positions could take "at". For example, "install the new street sign **at** the corner of the street." Or, "Put the logo **over** the first line of text.